# Is it possible to filter who is notified for a pull request?

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I'm somewhat new to git and Github but I've been using it for the past few months and I had a question regarding pull requests.

I would like to send a pull request to inform my team that my story branch is ready to be reviewed and merged into the feature branch. The problem is, 50 other people are watchers and will be informed even if this feature branch only applies to my small team.

**EDIT:** If you don't know what I mean by story and feature branch, basically a feature branch is a particular bigger change or addition to some project, small enough that one team can be assigned to working on it, and a story branch is a branch for individual divisible parts of that feature. It's not always needed but is good for keeping the feature branch clean for automated builds.

Am I going about pull requests the wrong way? Is it possible to filter which users are notified when I do a pull request? If so, how?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: "50 other people are watchers" - watchers of the whole project, but not subscribed directly to that pull request (as that doesn't exist at that point anyway), am I right?

Comment: Right, they're not participants in the pull request, but they will be informed it was created via email, which I'm trying to avoid by doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid what you exactly want is not possible with the current GitHub version.

Generally speaking I'd consider:

- if the project is not too big and shouldn't be splitted into more projects? You may use either git submodules or a language/framework related tool (Ruby gems, Python PyPI, PHP Composer, NodeJS NPM etc.). Each project then can have a separate notification settings.
- if it's not just about the notifications setup? Everyone can explicitly say if he wants receive emails with each change in the [Notification Settings](https://github.com/settings/notifications):

[image]

[Watching](https://help.github.com/articles/watching-repositories) the project allows you to be notified about new pull requests & issues and commits (= that's the purpose of that feature).

So the question here is **why are all the people watching the project and/or receiving emails when you're saying they don't care about pull requests**?

If they don't care, they can "unwatch" the project or turn off email updates for watched repositories.

Also there's an explicit **"Subscribe"** button within each pull request or issue which can be used by anyone who wants to watch that particular PR/issue:

[image]

Github also has **"Teams"**, it's mostly for permissions management, but you should be able to "@mention" a particular team: https://github.com/blog/1121-introducing-team-mentions (if you set up such team beforehand) in any particular issue/PR.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer, after spending a lot of time researching, I believe you are right. There really seems to be no way to do exactly what I want to do. I will look into some of those tools you mentioned but perhaps the answer is, as you suggested, to properly set up notification/watch settings per user. Of those 50 people, only a dozen or so should be watching it. I'll accept your answer because you give a few alternatives to achieve the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

It's been awhile since I asked this and there's been some changes to how we go about the review process, so I thought I'd give an update.

We started using a tool called [ReviewBoard](https://www.reviewboard.org/) for some projects. It basically hooks into git and prevents pushing to a particular branch you want to keep sanitized, requiring you to create a review request before pushing to that branch.

You do so via the following command:

```
rbt post -p
```

After creating a review, some privileged user will have to review and approve your change before you can push it.

There's some kinks in the process and we're still working it all out, but this seems to be working fairly well. We also had a team that looked at a tool called [gerrit](https://code.google.com/p/gerrit/), but that ultimately didn't work out.